# Why Firebase Messaging configurations are different for IOS native and Flutter iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently, I discovered, that Firebase cloud messaging for iOS native [requires additional code in AppDelegate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#register_for_remote_notifications)

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
  options: authOptions,
  completionHandler: { _, _ in }
)

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

But for [Flutter iOS setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#ios) there is no additional native code required.
Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is mainly because the tutorials follow a slightly different structure for iOS and flutter. In both cases, you will have to request for user permission at some point in your app.

Within the iOS tutorial, this is exactly what the above code lines achieve. As they are put inside AppDelegate.swift, the permission popup will appear right on application launch.

In the flutter tutorial, you can instead use the following code as described [in a following part of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive)

```
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: false,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: false,
  criticalAlert: false,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true,
);
```

The flutter tutorial does not specify a place on where to put these lines. You could chose to do it right after start of the application, then the user experience would be the same as in the iOS version.